How are appended assets from the Asset Browser handled, can i replicate this in python?
The Asset Browser does something special that I can't quite grasp:
If you drag a material from a library into the scene, on an object, it loads and appends it. If I modify this material (name, properties), and then try to drag that same, original material again from the Asset Browser, it does not create a new copy, but rather reuses and applies my modified version that is in the scene. I haven't tested it for non-material assets.
How does the Asset Browser check this? It's not name-based, it's not based on data comparing... Does it do some kind of uuid check, does the data block in Blender keep references to the library asset?
I'd love to replicate this behaviour when loading assets through code with Python!

Hello. You might want to read https://devtalk.blender.org/t/asset-linking-proposal/34127 which tackles this very subject and proposes alternatives. TLDR : it's not reliable and I don't think you can replicate the exact same behaviour in python.

Thanks, it makes sense, I had a feeling a lot on the asset browser is a special case, and not accessible through Python.
